# Adding a diagonal line for each subplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have generated 5 subplots using the following code:

```
fig = pylab.figure()

pylab.subplot(231)
pylab.scatter(x_a, y_a, color='darkorange')
pylab.title('Regression Model A')

pylab.subplot(232)
pylab.scatter(x_b, y_b, color='g')
pylab.title('Regression Model B')

pylab.subplot(233)
pylab.scatter(x_c, y_c, color='blue')
pylab.title('Regression Model C')

pylab.subplot(234)
pylab.scatter(x_d, y_d, color='r')
pylab.title('Regression Model D')

pylab.subplot(235)
pylab.scatter(x_e, y_e, color='purple')
pylab.title('Regression Model E')

plt.show()
```

I want to draw a diagonal line across each subplot. I Would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with machine learning, please do not use that tag unless you are *actually* asking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to plot the diagonal for each subplot, using the min and max of the data ranges for the xs and ys:

something like this, using fake data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     # use matplotlib.pyplot instead of the deprecated pylab
import random

# ------------  making fake data

def make_data():
    return [random.random() for _ in range(10)]

x_a, y_a = make_data(), make_data()
x_b, y_b = make_data(), make_data()
x_c, y_c = make_data(), make_data()
x_d, y_d = make_data(), make_data()
x_e, y_e = make_data(), make_data()

# ------------  end making fake data


def make_diagonal(x, y):   # uses the data for each plot to set the start end end points of the diagonal of each data set
    xx, yy = [min(x), max(x)], [min(y), max(y)]
    plt.plot(xx, yy)

fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(231)
plt.scatter(x_a, y_a, color='darkorange')
plt.title('Regression Model A')
make_diagonal(x_a, y_a)

plt.subplot(232)
plt.scatter(x_b, y_b, color='green')
plt.title('Regression Model B')
make_diagonal(x_b, y_b)

plt.subplot(233)
plt.scatter(x_c, y_c, color='blue')
plt.title('Regression Model C')
make_diagonal(x_c, y_c)

plt.subplot(234)
plt.scatter(x_d, y_d, color='red')
plt.title('Regression Model D')
make_diagonal(x_d, y_d)

plt.subplot(235)
plt.scatter(x_e, y_e, color='purple')
plt.title('Regression Model E')
make_diagonal(x_e, y_e)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!